# How do I use call() to set the value of `this` when using setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, prototype, this, settimeout

I making a simple game in javascript. These are my player methods (the part in question is calling the reset method half a second after the player hits the water):

```
Player.prototype = {
    update : function(){
        // player control and edge of screen detection
        // TODO factor out hardcoding into sprite width constants
        if (this.keyPressed === 'right' && this.x < 400){
            this.x += 100;
        }
        if (this.keyPressed === 'left' && this.x > 10){
            this.x += -100;
        }
        if (this.keyPressed === 'up' && this.y > 10){
            this.y -= 83;
        }
        if (this.keyPressed === 'down' && this.y < 400){
            this.y -= -83;
        }
        // reset key press
        this.keyPressed = null;

        // if reaches water, reset position
        if (this.y < 60) {
            setTimeout(this.reset, 500);
        }
    },
    reset : function(){
        // TODO factor these constants out
        // console.logs for testing
        console.log("a");
        console.log(this);
        this.x = 200;
        this.y = 405;
        console.log(this.x);
    },
    render : function(){
        ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y);
    },
    handleInput : function(e){
        this.keyPressed = e;
    }
}
```

My problem is, when `update` calls `reset`, the keyword `this` is not bound to `player`, but to `window`.

I could just just include `player.x` and `player.y` in `reset`, but does that defeat the point of writing the methods in a prototype?

I had the idea of using `call()` to set the value of `this`, but I can't seem to get it working with `setTimeout()`. This doesn't work (error: object is not a function):

```
setTimeout(this.reset.call, 500, this);
```

..and neither does this (reset executes correctly but immediately):

```
setTimeout(this.reset.call(this), 500);
```

So how do I set `this` to `player` and pass it to `reset` with `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. `call` will **immediately** call the function so you'll pass its *return* value to `setTimeout`.

Use `bind` instead. `bind` generates a new function which calls the original function with a different context (and default variables).

```
setTimeout(this.reset.bind(this), 500);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use bind:

```
setTimeout(this.reset.bind(this), 500);
```